# Change name of document class - Flash CS Pro

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timeline, document-class

In document class, constructor, following line produces following error:

```
name = "hello world";
Error: Error #2078: The name property of a Timeline-placed object cannot be modified.
```

Is this doable or hackable?

Comment: because using "name" means changing the instance name of the object

Comment: I want to get instance by name. I know it's at index 0 but I wanted to have a more generic implementation.

Comment: You don't instantiate the Document Class neither in the timeline nor by code, you just set it in the .FLA's Property tab as "Document Class"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some test, and it seems you can't.
"MainTimeline is the default class used for the document class. The document class is the display object which is added to the stage when the SWF movie is loaded. Underneath it is a normal class which extends MovieClip." (found here on SO)
Probably the implementation of this class blocks you to change its name. As you're not instantiating it, probably flash assign a name to this instance and doesn't want you to change it :)